# Displaying multiple results from nested query?

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing an appointment book type thing, and i have a table for just possible times, so my first query is to list all of the times, then my 2nd table is scheduled appointments, which lists inside the table the appointment if its time and date match the time and date pulled from the first query.

What i cannot figure out is if 2 entries on the 2nd query match the criteria to display both results at the same time.

Heres my setup:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM times", $db);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $time = $row[time];
    $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM appts WHERE time = '$time' AND date = '$date' ", $db);
    $apt = mysql_fetch_array($query2);
    $aptid = $apt[id];
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo date('h:i A', strtotime($row[time]));
    echo "</td><td>$apt[name]</td></td><td>$apt[phone]</td><td>$apt[phone2]</td><td>$apt[src]</td><td>$apt[coach]</td><td>$apt[comments]</td><td>";
    if($aptid != ''){
        echo "<a href='index.php?date=$date&apptid=$aptid&action=delete'>Delete</a> &nbsp; <a href='index.php?date=$date&apptid=$aptid&action=x'>X</a> &nbsp; <a href='index.php?date=$date&apptid=$aptid&action=ns'>NS</a>";
    }
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
```

E.G.: 2 appointments set for 9am, its only displaying the first one. [See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orpq7.png)

[image]

Comment: Could you post an excerpt of the `appts` table? It's hard to check the query without the structure/content.

Comment: Are you expecting no more than one appointment for one possible time?

Comment: Can you provide an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) ?

Comment: MySQL isn't built to natively support nested resultsets. You'll need to implement your own way of iterating over appointments.

Comment: @MatthewFitzGerald-Chamberlain heres what the appts table looks like http://i.imgur.com/hHKVvRU.png

Comment: @Warthel4578 in a perfect world, no, but i'm assuming it will most definitely happen. only other option would be list a few of the same time but thats extremely clunky

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify it to

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM times", $db);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $time = $row[time];
    $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM appts WHERE time = '$time' AND date = '$date' ", $db);

    while($apt = mysql_fetch_array($query2))
   {
    $aptid = $apt[id];
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo date('h:i A', strtotime($row[time]));
    echo "</td><td>$apt[name]</td></td><td>$apt[phone]</td><td>$apt[phone2]</td><td>$apt[src]</td><td>$apt[coach]</td><td>$apt[comments]</td><td>";
    if($aptid != ''){
        echo "<a href='index.php?date=$date&apptid=$aptid&action=delete'>Delete</a> &nbsp; <a href='index.php?date=$date&apptid=$aptid&action=x'>X</a> &nbsp; <a href='index.php?date=$date&apptid=$aptid&action=ns'>NS</a>";
    }
    echo "</td></tr>";
 }
}
```

You have to run another nested loop inside.

Comment: Doesnt do exactly what i need but definitely how i need to do it. Thank you, i hopefully can figure it out from here!

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_array will only fetch one row of data. From the php manual:

> mysql_fetch_array — Fetch a result row as an associative array, a
>   numeric array, or both

That means you need to loop to get multiple appointments, just like the first loop:

```
while($apt = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) {
    $aptid = $apt[id];
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo date('h:i A', strtotime($row[time]));
    echo "</td><td>$apt[name]</td></td><td>$apt[phone]</td><td>$apt[phone2]</td><td>$apt[src]</td><td>$apt[coach]</td><td>$apt[comments]</td><td>";
    if($aptid != ''){
        echo "<a href='index.php?date=$date&apptid=$aptid&action=delete'>Delete</a> &nbsp; <a href='index.php?date=$date&apptid=$aptid&action=x'>X</a> &nbsp; <a href='index.php?date=$date&apptid=$aptid&action=ns'>NS</a>";
    }
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
```